# How to check if two boolean expressions are equivalent

Tags: java, boolean-logic

How can I know if two boolean expresions are equivalent?

```
String expr1 = "(A or B) and C";
String expr2 = "C and (B or A)";
boolean equals = areExprsEquals(expr1, expr2);
```

I think I should...

1. Parse the expresion storing it in some structure data
2. Reduce the expresion in OR groups
3. Check if the two expresions have the same groups

For example, with the step two I get:

```
Expr1
(A or B) and C
Converted to:
(A and C) or (B and C)

Expr2
C and (B or A)
Converted to:
(C and B) or (C and A)
```

Now I have to know if have the same groups. One way can be getting the hash of each group:

Exp1:

```
group 1: 
(A and C)
Order:
(A and C)
Hash:
md5("a&c")

group 2:
(B and C)
Order:
(B and C)
Hash:
md5("b&c")
```

Exp2:

```
group 1: 
(C and B)
Order:
(B and C)
Hash:
md5("b&c")

group 2:
(C and A)
Order:
(A and C)
Hash:
md5("a&c")
```

So:

```
expr1: md5( sort(md5("a&c"), md5("b&c") ))
expr2: md5( sort(md5("b&c"), md5("a&c") ))
```

I can do the md5 of each group, sort, and the expr hash is the md5 of all hashs.

But the problem is... How can I reduce the exprs? Is there any algorithm? The expressions use only AND and OR operators.

Comment: All in all, a really BIG question. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem

Comment: To put it short: if you would have some magical algorithm that could solve your problem with good performance in decent time with respect to the size to the input data, this very same algorithm could also manage most of the computationally worst problems known.

Comment: Are "(A or B) and C" and "(D or E) and F" equivalent?

Comment: No @GilbertLeBlanc. In the wiki, there are Online SAT solvers written in JavaScript, maybe I should start looking their code.

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc -  Are you tempting us? The variables are different, so this is equivalent to asking if x=y for any x,y.

Comment: @Gyro Gearloose: Not quite.  I wanted to find out if the symbols themselves mattered.  The usual way to find equivalence is to create a logical truth table for each expression;

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc so this is a different question. But I guess the original poster is not really interested what happens when variable names change. Just a guess - and I don't see any relevant impact on the final answer.

Comment: In my real problem the variables have to be the same. For this reason I have to sort them and use a hash function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any algorithm?

Theoretical answer:

- The problem your are trying to solve is the [Boolean Satisfiability Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) also known as SAT.
- It is [NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete).
- THAT MEANS, that there are no known algorithms<sup>1</sup> that always find a solution for a SAT problem in polynomial time; i.e. no algorithm that whose worst case is `O(N^C)` or better, where `C` is a constant and N is the number of variables in the SAT problem.
- There is an obvious solution that is `O(2^N)` ... brute-force search of the solution space.  Better algorithms exist; see [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#Algorithms_for_solving_SAT) but they are all exponential in the worst-case.

Practical solutions:

- For really small `N`, brute force may give acceptable performance.
- Use an existing SAT solver, bearing in mind that the theory says that it has exponential behavior in the worst case.
- Avoid problems with large `N` ... or code your application so that the solver is "time boxed"; i.e. it gives up if it can't get a solution in a prescribed time.

---

<sup>1 - If it is ever proven that [P == NP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem), then better algorithms may emerge for this and other NP-complete problems.</sup>

Comment: I don't believe this is correct. The question is asking about equivalence of Boolean formulas (which is Co-NP-complete) not SAT (which is NP-complete).  As long as P=! NP, this means that this question *cannot* be NP-complete (however, it also means it cannot be in P).

Comment: @wanderingmathematician - Could you (or someone else) provide me an online reference?