# Algorithm for enumerating all permutations of algebraic expressions

Tags: algorithm, combinations, permutation, computer-science

If I have a list of variables, such as {**A**, **B**, **C**} and a list of operators, such as {**AND**, **OR**}, how can I efficiently enumerate all permutations of valid expressions?

Given the above, I would want to see as output (assuming evaluation from left-to-right with no operator precedence):

- A AND B AND C
- A OR B OR C
- A AND B OR C
- A AND C OR B
- B AND C OR A
- A OR B AND C
- A OR C AND B
- B OR C AND A

I believe that is an exhaustive enumeration of all combinations of inputs. I don't want to be redundant, so for example, I wouldn't add "C OR B AND A" because that is the same as "B OR C AND A".

Any ideas of how I can come up with an algorithm to do this? I really have no idea where to even start.

Comment: Maybe I should try to list all possible expressions in conjunctive normal form?

Comment: What is the maximum number of variables that you could have?

Comment: I'd  start by enumerating all of the operator combinations. With two operators there are four combinations. Then, for those portions of the expression that are commutative, you need to choose k of N remaining variables as the operands. For example, with `_ OR _ OR _` the whole expression is commutative, so k=3 and N=3 and there's only one way to choose the operands (3C3=1). With `_ OR _ AND _`, the first OR is commutative, so k=2 and N=3, and there are three choices for the operands (3C2=3).

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is a simple option to go:

```
void AllPossibilities(variables, operators, index, currentExpression){
    if(index == variables.size) {
        print(currentExpression);
        return;
    }
    foreach(v in variables){
        foreach(op in operators){
            AllPossibilities(variables, operators, index + 1, v + op);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to avoid listing equivalent expressions. For example, I don't want to find "A OR B" and then also have "B OR A" because they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an easy problem. First, you need a notion of grouping, because

`(A AND B) OR C != A AND (B OR C)`

Second, you need to generate all expressions. This will mean iterating through every permutation of terms, and grouping of terms in the permutation.

Third, you have to actually parse every expression, bringing the parsed expressions into a canonical form (say, CNF. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree#Construction_of_an_expression_tree)

Finally, you have to actually check equivalence of the expressions seen so far. This is checking equivalence of the AST formed by parsing.

It will look loosely like this.

```
INPUT: terms
0. unique_expressions = empty_set
1. for p_t in permutations of terms:
2.   for p_o in permutations of operations:
3.     e = merge_into_expression(p_t, p_o)
4.     parsed_e = parse(e)
5.     already_seen = False
6.     for unique_e in unique_expressions:
7.       if equivalent(parsed_e, unique_e)
8.         already_seen = True
9.         break
10.    if not already_seen:
11.      unique_expressions.add(parsed_e)
```

For more info, check out this post. [How to check if two boolean expressions are equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33767980/how-to-check-if-two-boolean-expressions-are-equivalent)